# Reverse LaTeXing

Tags: pdftex, latex-misc

My system got formatted completely. I dont have any files related to tex. So I installed TeXLive and texmaker on my pc. But yes, I have the pdf generated by the tex file. Is it possible to get my tex file using the pdf?If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I don't think it is.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be possible. A pdf can be generated by a lot of software.The best you can do, if it's not too lond a document, is to extract the text from the pdf and try to redo the tex structure.